# Missing /usr/local/sbin directory in the /etc/paths file

Tags: path, environment-variables

Why doesn’t the `/etc/paths` file include the `/usr/local/sbin` directory on macOS?

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

I would have expected:

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

**Note.** — The `/etc/paths` file is read by the `/etc/profile` shell script to generate the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/usr/local/sbin` directory does not exist on a default macOS installation, but you can easily add it yourself.

To add that directory to the system-wide `PATH` environment variable (for all users), as there is always the risk of a macOS update overwriting `/etc/paths`, it might be better to add a file named `usr_local_sbin` (or anything else) to `/etc/paths.d` with that single line:

```
/usr/local/sbin
```

This will put the `/usr/local/sbin` path in a position close to the end of `PATH`, which usually (assuming unique command names) is not a problem. If you want to have it early in `PATH` for whatever reason, either add to  `/etc/paths` nevertheless or edit the `PATH` order in the user-specific `~/.profile`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussions, [they have been moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71067/discussion-between-patrix-and-maggyero).

Comment: "Edit the `PATH` order in the user-specific profile" — Here's a one-liner you can put anywhere in `.profile` (or `.zprofile` or `.zshrc` in modern versions of macOS if you haven't changed your default shell to Bash) to do just that, inserting `/usr/local/sbin` between `/bin` and `/usr/sbin`: `PATH="$(echo $PATH | sed -E 's#(^.*:/bin):(/usr/sbin:.*$)#\1:/usr/local/sbin:\2#')"`